# Trying to modify express.js to work with React-Router but express doesn't receive any GET request from browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, http-status-code-404

As you everybody know, BrowserRouter from react-router doesn't work if you type URL directly in the URL bar.
And I found solution here:
[React router doesn't work on express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227859/react-router-doesnt-work-on-express-server)
here says I should handle Get request using

```
app.get()
```

But that doesn't work for me.
My react has port number 8081 and express has port 8000.
URL of my react-router component is http://localhost:8081/chat/room
React-router works fine, shows component when I click Link, but navigating to the component using URL throws Cannot GET chat/room error. Status is 404.

As the answer tells, I added code which should handle GET request:

**app.js in express.js**

```
//main javascript file for nodejs. server

const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors =require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const chatRouter = require('./router/chatRouter.js');
const authRouter = require('./router/authRouter.js');
const redis = require ('./redis/redis');
const { RedisClient } = require('redis');
const redisStore= require('connect-redis')(session);
//cors setting
app.use(cors({
 origin:'http://localhost:8081',
 credentials:true
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
//redis
const createdClientRedis = redis.createRedisClient();
app.use(
 session({
 resave:false,
 saveUninitialized:false,
 secret:"secret key",
 cookie:{
   httpOnly:true,
   secure:false
  },
  store:new RedisClient({createdClientRedis})
 })
);

//Routers
app.use('/chat',chatRouter);
app.use('/auth',authRouter);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});
```

**chatRouter**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const chatDatabase = require('../chat/db/chatDB.js');
router.use(express.json());
const indexFile = path.resolve(__dirname,"../../../client/src/app.html");
console.log(indexFile);
router.get('*',(req,res)=>{
  console.log("this is router get");
  res.sendFile(indexFile);
});
```

I thought when I visit localhost:8081/chat/room, browser should send a GET request to the express server. And because I send all /chat to chatRouter, I thought chatRouter will handle GET request.

But!
router.get in chatRouter does nothing. Just nothing.

[image]

*this is router get* is not displayed on console. My guess is browser is not sending GET request to the server because react and expressjs have different port numbers.

I found router.get works if I change browser URL's port number to express fort number (localhost:8081... -> localhost:8000/chat/room)

this is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'bundlefile.js'
  },
  performance:{
    maxAssetSize:500000
  },
module: {
  rules : [
     {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [ 'babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
     }
    ]
},
plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/app.html'
   })
],
 devServer:{
   port:8081
 }
}
```

**what I tried **
I tried to add two lines in webpack.config.js

```
historyApiFallback:true //in devServer
outputPath:"/" // in output
```

but did not work. How should I do to receive Get request in express.js when I visit localhost:8081/chat/room ?