# How to separate the frontend routing from backend endpoints?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have an express server which handle some routes

```
/users/login
/users/register 
/orders/add

and so on..
```

serving a static files, in the default route
"/"

so, if user navigated to domain.com for example

it will navigate to that static files

these static files are a react frontend app

the default url "/" will navigate to a login page

and "/dashboard" will navigate to another page

what actually happen, is there's kind of conflict between the backend and frontend routes

for example

if user navigated to "/dashboard"

the expected result is to navigate him to the frontend page

what actual happen is "the backend handle that route not the frontend" and simply return : "I don't have that route (404)

What was in my mind is to navigate any not handled route to the frontend

using that code

```
  app.get('*', async function (request, reply) {
    return reply.sendFile('index.html')
  })
```

however, not solved my problem

Comment: give prefix to backend routes, ex. /api

Comment: @squarer already did that, however did not help "/" route to login, "/api" or "/api/*" route to a "not found page in my front end", but "/dashboard" return 404, not exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router doesn't work on express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227859/react-router-doesnt-work-on-express-server)

Comment: I should fixed that issue, by separating frontend and backend routes, to have a different server for the react app, if that may help someone