# navigator() Page navigation not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, express, npm

LoginForm.jsx

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import axios from 'axios';
import './loginstyle.css'
function LoginForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate(); 

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/login', { name, password });

      if (response.data === 'Login successful') {
        // Redirect to admin panel
        navigate('/admin');
      } else {
        // Handle failed login here
        setError(response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setError('An error occurred');
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="LoginForm">
        <div className="login-head">ADMIN LOGIN</div>
        <div className="login-body">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            {error && <p>{error}</p>}
            <div className="login-btn">
              <button type="submit" placeholder="LOGIN">
                LOGIN
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

app.js

```
import LoginPage from './components/LoginForm/LoginForm';
import AdminPage from './components/AdminPanel/AdminPanel';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

import "./App.css";
function App() {


  return (
   <BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<LoginPage/>}></Route>
      <Route path='/admin' element={<AdminPage/>}></Route>
   </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want a admin login page. If the username and password is true i want to navigate to /admin page but it is only showing login successful under the password input. I am using express,mongoDB as backend.
even though when I enter the URL http://localhost:3000/admin it is showing Unexpected Application Error!
404 Not Found. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router doesn't work on express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227859/react-router-doesnt-work-on-express-server)